# Is it possible to add a normal map to a material?

Tags: texturing, materials, texture-baking, normal-map, pbr

I am using sketchup for modelling and applying textures, then export the model to blender to uv unwrap and bake it to a single texture map and add ao.
I usually just use photoshop to generate a normal map of the finished texture file which is a bit imprecise especially on larger texture maps.
So i was wondering if it was possible if I generated the normal maps for each material individually in photoshop to then somehow add that in blender and bake it to a single normal map texture file just like you do it with the regular texture. I am still using 2.79 if that's important.
Thanks in advance!